# LINQ Query with join, group by and Sum()

Tags: mysql, linq, join, sum

I've working on this for a while so I thought I'd post here to see if anyone has any idea how a query like the following can be converted to LINQ.

Here is the MySQL Query:

```
SELECT SUM(line_ord.itemqty) AS LineOrderQTY, SUM(assemblyNumber.qty) AS 
AssemblyQTY FROM line_ord 
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT sum(assemblyno.qty) AS qty, assemblyno.row_id FROM assemblyno 
    INNER JOIN line_ord ON assemblyno.row_id = line_ord.row_id
    WHERE line_ord.bdnum = 'S61460'
) AS assemblyNumber ON line_ord.row_id = assemblyNumber.row_id
WHERE line_ord.bdnum = 'S61460'
```

This what I have so far for the LINQ query, but it doesn't return the proper results.

```
var items = (from c in Context.OrderLineItemData
        join e in Context.AssemblyLabelData on c.ID equals e.RowID
                     where c.BreakdownNumber == breakdownNumber

                     group c by c.BreakdownNumber into g
                     select new
                     {                             
                          AssemblyQuantity= g.Sum(x => x.Quantity),
                          LineOrdQuantity = g.Sum(**WHAT GOES HERE?**)
                     }).FirstOrDefault()
```

I did manage to get it to work like this, but it seems kind of messy to me.

```
            var items = (from c in Context.OrderLineItemData
                     join e in Context.AssemblyLabelData on c.ID equals e.RowID
                     where c.BreakdownNumber == breakdownNumber

                     group c by c into g
                     select new
                     {                             
                          AssemblyQuantity= g.Sum(x => x.Quantity),
                          LineOrdQuantity = (from e in Context.OrderLineItemData where e.BreakdownNumber == breakdownNumber select e.Quantity).Sum()
                     }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got my answer.  Seems like a query object has to be created and then I can use it to preform my calculations.

```
var items = (from od in Context.OrderLineItemData
             join ad in Context.AssemblyLabelData on od.ID equals ad.RowID into odGroup
             from g in odGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
             where od.BreakdownNumber == breakdownNumber
             group g by new
             {
                  breakdown = od.BreakdownNumber,
                  LineOrd = od,
                  AssemblyQty = g == null ? 0 : g.Quantity
             }
             into groupped
             select new
             {
                   Breakdown = groupped.Key.breakdown,
                   AssemblyQty = groupped.Sum(x => x.Quantity),
                   lineOrdQty = groupped.Key.LineOrd.Quantity
             }
         );            
        int remainingQuantity = items.Sum(x => x.lineOrdQty) - items.Sum(x => x.AssemblyQty);
```